# MP Floating point structure

Tags: c, operating-system

I was going through the XV-6 code through which it identifies the MP structure. It first searches in first kb of EBDA. The code it like this

```
static struct mp*
mpsearch(void)
{
  uchar *bda;
  uint p;
  struct mp *mp;

  bda = (uchar *) P2V(0x400);
  if((p = ((bda[0x0F]<<8)| bda[0x0E]) << 4)){
    if((mp = mpsearch1(p, 1024)))
      return mp;
  } else {
    p = ((bda[0x14]<<8)|bda[0x13])*1024;
    if((mp = mpsearch1(p-1024, 1024)))
      return mp;
  }
  return mpsearch1(0xF0000, 0x10000);
}
```

I don't understand what does this line `if((p = ((bda[0x0F]<<8)| bda[0x0E]) << 4))` do.

Answer (score 0):

[1.2 BIOS Data Area (BDA)](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)#BIOS_Data_Area_.28BDA.29)

> 0x040E (word)  EBDA base address >> 4 (usually!)

The purpose of `p = ((bda[0x0F]<<8)| bda[0x0E]) << 4` is to extract a 20bit address to indicate the first kilobyte of EBDA.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?